# Correct way to understand local_ in ghidra disassembly

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis, x86, gdb, ghidra

Attached is the part of a disassembled main from a x86 binary file, generated by ghidra.

```
                             **************************************************************
                             *                          FUNCTION                          *
                             **************************************************************
                             undefined main(undefined1 param_1)
             undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>                                XREF[1]:     0804835e(W)  
             undefined1        Stack[0x4]:1   param_1                                 XREF[1]:     08048309(*)  
             undefined4        EAX:4          str_in                                  XREF[1]:     0804835e(W)  
             undefined4        Stack[0x0]:4   local_res0                              XREF[1]:     08048310(R)  
             undefined4        Stack[-0x10]:4 local_10                                XREF[6]:     08048358(R), 
                                                                                                   08048363(W), 
                                                                                                   0804836d(R), 
                                                                                                   08048388(R), 
                                                                                                   08048393(W), 
                                                                                                   0804839d(R)  
             undefined4        Stack[-0x14]:4 local_14                                XREF[2]:     0804831a(W), 
                                                                                                   08048366(R)  
             undefined4        Stack[-0x18]:4 local_18                                XREF[2]:     08048321(W), 
                                                                                                   08048396(R)  
             undefined4        Stack[-0x2c]:4 local_2c                                XREF[3]:     08048369(W), 
                                                                                                   08048399(W), 
                                                                                                   080483ac(W)  
             undefined4        Stack[-0x30]:4 local_30                                XREF[12]:    08048328(*), 
                                                                                                   08048334(*), 
                                                                                                   08048340(*), 
                                                                                                   0804834c(*), 
                                                                                                   0804835b(*), 
                                                                                                   08048370(*), 
                                                                                                   0804837c(*), 
                                                                                                   0804838b(*), 
                                                                                                   080483a0(*), 
                                                                                                   080483b4(*), 
                                                                                                   080483c2(*), 
                                                                                                   080483d0(*)  
                             main                                            XREF[2]:     Entry Point(*), 
                                                                                          _start:08048167(*)  
        08048309 8d 4c 24 04     LEA        ECX=>param_1,[ESP + 0x4]
        0804830d 83 e4 f0        AND        ESP,0xfffffff0
        08048310 ff 71 fc        PUSH       dword ptr [ECX + local_res0]
        08048313 55              PUSH       EBP
        08048314 89 e5           MOV        EBP,ESP
        08048316 51              PUSH       ECX
        08048317 83 ec 24        SUB        ESP,0x24
        0804831a c7 45 f4        MOV        dword ptr [EBP + local_14],DAT_080a6b19          = 6Ah    j
                 19 6b 0a 08
        08048321 c7 45 f0        MOV        dword ptr [EBP + local_18],s_the_ripper_080a6b1e = "the ripper"
                 1e 6b 0a 08
```

Same code from gdb

```
   0x08048309 <+0>: lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x0804830d <+4>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x08048310 <+7>: push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x08048313 <+10>:    push   ebp
   0x08048314 <+11>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048316 <+13>:    push   ecx
   0x08048317 <+14>:    sub    esp,0x24
=> 0x0804831a <+17>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x80a6b19
```

Why is ghidra changeing `[ebp-0xc]` to `[EBP + local_14]`.
Similar question I found is [Ghidra interpreting stack pointers wrongly](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23540/ghidra-interpreting-stack-pointers-wrongly) but reading the answer, I'm not getting the meaning of `[EBP + local_14]` Here, is ghidra just renaming `-0xc` to a easily readable name like `local_14`? I'm not getting how to make sense of this exactly.

In the function header, it is shown that `Stack[-0x10]:4 local_10`. I assume it means that `local_10` is 4 byte variable at Stack[-0x10], where Stack is the stack pointer upon entry to function. But why is it added to ebp. What's the meaning of that representation used by ghidra?

Comment: Before doing anything with Ghidra, I start to help Ghidra by telling it the return types of functions ( `int`, `void`, `char *`, etc ). Then I do the same for the function parameters.  Just this step alone starts to clear up the local variables.  Did you try that ?

Comment: One thing you can do that may make this more obvious is to turn off the setting that causes Ghidra to use the `local_` variables directly in the assembly. You can do this via `Edit -> Tool Options -> Listing Fields -> Operands Field -> Markup Stack Variable References`. This will change the display to show the normal operands, with an arrow indicating what stack variable is being referenced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since local variables are usually placed on the stack in `x86` and `esp` register can change during function execution, it is more convenient to save the value of `esp` register on function entry and access data relatively to that value. `ebp` register is used for this purpose. So you will often see

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

lines at the begining of functions. In the example you have provided it is the case - all local variables are accessed this way, through `ebp`.

Now, there are two different naming conventions for local variables:

- first and more natural one: if `[ebp - xxx]` is accessed, it will be displayed as `[ebp + local_xxx]`. Here, `local_xxx = -xxx`, so for instance, `local_18 = -0x18`.
- second and less intuitive one makes use of the `esp` value at the beginning of a function. In your example, two dwords are pushed on the stack before `mov ebp, esp` line. It means, that if some local variable was called `local_xxx` in the first convention, in the second one it will be named `local_xxx+0x8`, for instance `local_18` in the first one will be `local_20` in the second one, used by Ghidra.

Why do we add `0x8` in the second one? Because two dwords (`8` bytes) were pushed onto the stack before `esp` value was saved into `ebp` and in `x86` architecture stack "grows downwards", which means if you push something onto it, this value will be saved there and `esp` will be *decreased* accordingly (in this case, twice, by `4` bytes). So, in your particular example, you have the instruction

```
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x80a6b19
```

which would be displayed as

```
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp+local_c],0x80a6b19
```

in the first convention and

```
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp+local_14],0x80a6b19
```

in the second one, implemented in Ghidra, since `0xc + 0x8 = 0x14`.

Comment: Just to confirm. In the second convention, when it shows `ebp+local_14` , ebp actually mean the value of esp at the beginning of of the function call and not the value of ebp when the instruction is ran?

Comment: No, it is current ebp value (which is entry_esp-8).

Comment: then value of local_14 should be -0xC right. Else it'll point to wrong memory location when added with ebp

Comment: Exactly. And that's why I called this convention "less intuitive".